# Question about CLRS problem 19.4-1

Tags: algorithms, heaps, linked-lists

I'm working on problem 19.4-1 from the CLRS book, which asks to show that the height of an n-node Fibonacci heap can be greater than O(lg n) by exhibiting a sequence of operations that creates a Fibonacci heap consisting of just one tree that is a linear chain of n nodes.

I'm not sure if by "linear chain" the problem means a linked list. Can anyone clarify this for me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Correct, a singly linked list.